# Rendering route polyline using MKMapView with a border iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mkmapview

So I **can't get the border polyline to be rendered below the main polyline**, I am able to do it if I use coordinates but wont work with the route. I need it to be rendered as the route. I'm pretty sure the fix is going to be in 'for route in response.routes {}'. Any help is appreciated, I had used a previous thread to help me get this far but they weren't using routes and was were using coordinates instead.

previous thread:[How to add border to MKPolyline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58810993/how-to-add-border-to-mkpolyline)

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {

    var startingLocation: String
    var destinationLocation: String
    var avoidTolls: Bool

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        let mapView = MKMapView()
        mapView.delegate = context.coordinator

        // Get the coordinates for the starting and destination locations
        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()

        geocoder.geocodeAddressString(startingLocation) { [weak mapView] (placemarks, error) in
            guard let mapView = mapView,
                  let placemark = placemarks?.first,
                  let startingCoordinate = placemark.location?.coordinate else {
                return
            }
        
            geocoder.geocodeAddressString(destinationLocation) { [weak mapView] (placemarks, error) in
                guard let mapView = mapView,
                      let placemark = placemarks?.first,
                      let destinationCoordinate = placemark.location?.coordinate else {
                    return
                }
                
                
                // Display the route on the map
                let directionRequest = MKDirections.Request()
                
                if avoidTolls {
                    directionRequest.tollPreference = .avoid // Avoid tolls
                } else {
                    directionRequest.tollPreference = .any
                }
                
                directionRequest.source = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: startingCoordinate))
                directionRequest.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: destinationCoordinate))
                directionRequest.transportType = .automobile
                
                let directions = MKDirections(request: directionRequest)
                directions.calculate { response, error in
                    guard let response = response else { return }
                    
                    
//                    let coordinates = [startingCoordinate, destinationCoordinate]
//
//                    // Instantiate the main polyline
//                    let mainPolyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: coordinates, count: coordinates.count)
//                    mainPolyline.title = "main"
//                    // Instantiate the border polyline
//                    let borderPolyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: coordinates, count: coordinates.count)
                    
                    
                    
                    let annotations = [MKAnnotation]()
                    for route in response.routes {
                        // Instantiate the main polyline
                        let mainPolyline = route.polyline
                        mainPolyline.title = "main"
                        // Instantiate the border polyline
                        let borderPolyline = route.polyline
                        mapView.addOverlay(mainPolyline)
                        //add border polyline
                        mapView.insertOverlay(borderPolyline, below: mainPolyline)
                        
                        mapView.showAnnotations(annotations, animated: true)
                
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return mapView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ view: MKMapView, context: Context) {}

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }


    class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
        var parent: MapView

        init(_ parent: MapView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        
    

        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
           let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
            // Use different colors for the border and the main polyline
            renderer.strokeColor = overlay.title == "main" ? UIColor(red: 24/255, green: 100/255, blue: 230/255, alpha: 1.0) : .black
                // Make the border polyline bigger. Their difference will be like the borderWidth of the main polyline
                renderer.lineWidth = overlay.title == "main" ? 6 : 8
                // Other polyline customizations
                renderer.lineCap = .round
                renderer.lineJoin = .bevel
                return renderer
                }
    }
}
```

Used this previous thread [How to add border to MKPolyline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58810993/how-to-add-border-to-mkpolyline) and I was able to get it to work using coordinates but I just could not get it to work using the route, not user why.